# I am trying to make the Bmi calculator using flutter but got many errors

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({@required this.colour, this.cardChild, this.onPress}); // i am getting errors here
  final Color colour ;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress(),
      child: Container(
//if box decoration is there in the code then the color property should go in the box decoration property
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color:colour,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i am getting  error: The parameter 'onPress', 'cardChild', 'colour' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. in the dart analysis

Answer (score 0):

The error you facing is caused by null-safety, you may want to change your types from:

```dart
final Color colour ;
final Widget cardChild;
final Function onPress;

//to

final Color? colour ;
final Widget? cardChild;
final Function? onPress;
```

But I recommend you to put them all in the constructor with the decorator `@required`

You can learn more about null-safety syntaxes on the official documentation:
https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety

Comment: I tried your way but then i cant use onpress() after that in the code above

Comment: What error did you face with the `onPress` argument ?

Comment: The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'

Comment: You have to use `onPress!` since you are "sure" that this argument will not be null

Comment: thanks for the help but again its showing the following error: Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: i am getting the following error with your solution can u help me out in this error : Null check operator used on a null value

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, even using the `@required` decorator wasn't enough to solve the issue,
What solved it for me was that i had to disable the *null-safety* for the project and that's by *downgrading the flutter version* from ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0" to ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0" through modifying the **pubspec.yaml** file. Specifically under dependencies -> sdk.

*Keep in mind that by downgrading the project's flutter version will disable the entire usage of null-safety including the "?" checking operator*

Here's a good read from Flutter Docs to better understand the null-safety feature in the Dart language :
https://dart.dev/null-safety#enable-null-safety

This is a good comprehensive article as well
https://petercoding.com/flutter/2021/03/04/using-null-safety-in-dart/

Answer (score 0):

I added 'required' to the constructor for onPress.
However, I could not directly assign it to the onTap: part of the GestureDetector widget. So I called it from a method that did match the expected method signature for onTap.
In the end this is the (inelegant) solution that worked for me:

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {

ReusableCard({required this.colour, this.cardChild, required this.onPress});

final Color colour;
final Widget? cardChild;
final Function onPress;

void onPressAction() {
    onPress();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
    onTap: onPressAction,
    child: Container(
      child: cardChild,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: colour,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```